# Rails: Users save they favorite posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

First sorry for my English;

For learning purpose I have create a blog with authentication ( I am using Devise), Now I want that user to be able to save other users posts so when they visit the Saved posts pages they will see posts saved, how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model the association

Business Logic

- Users can have multiple posts
- Users can save multiple posts
- A Post can be saved by multiple users but have one owner